# Comparing the plots of two functions in number theory

Tags: plotting, series-expansion, number-theory, approximation

**Definition.**

For $x>1$, let
$$R(x):=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\,\operatorname{li}(x^{1/n})$$
denote the Riemann prime counting function. If you are not familiar with the mathematical expressions used, this won't be a problem since the [function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RiemannR.html) is implemented in Mathematica as `RiemannR[x]`.

---

I want to plot these two functions

$$\sum_{m=1}^NR(x^{-2m})\quad\text{and}\quad -\frac{1}{\log x}+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\frac{\pi}{\log x}$$

next to each other. Here $N\gg1$ denotes a large natural number, ideally $N\to\infty$.

---

My code so far is

```
Plot[Sum[RiemannR[x^(-2*m)],{m,1,Infinity}],-1/(Log[x])+1/Pi*ArcTan[Pi/(Log[x])],{x,0,40},
PlotRange ->All]
```

but it doesn't work. I want to find out numerically if these functions are equal for $N\to\infty$ or if the second function is just an approximation, so precision is important.

Comment: Yes because you need to wrap the things you're plotting in a `List` so it's `Plot[{f[x], g[x], h[x], ...}, {x,0,40}]` in order to plot multiple things at once - notice the curly brackets. That doesn't fix it completely though because the sum isn't converging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't plot from 0 because the Log(0) is infinite, and you can't plot from 1 because Log(1) is zero and you are dividing by that. So let's start from 2:

```
end = 10;
Plot[{Sum[RiemannR[x^(-2*m)], {m, 1, end}], 
      1/(Log[x]) - 1/Pi*ArcTan[Pi/(Log[x])]}, 
      {x, 2, end}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: What value of `big` are you using?

Comment: Thanks. Could you please insert a graph where $1/\pi$ is multiplied and not added?

Comment: OK -- I also corrected the sign error so that now the two curves line up.

Comment: I agree that it looks like it... but 10 is a long way from infinity!

Comment: There's a small benefit from using `Evaluate@` on the argument to `Plot`